# Запятая перед "или 101 %"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

> Общее количество детей составит 1235 человек или 101 % от общего количества учащихся.

Нужна ли запятая перед или. Думаю, что нужна, можно заменить на "то есть". Правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общее количество детей составит 1235 человек, или 101 % от общего количества учащихся.

Союз ИЛИ является пояснительным, можно заменить на "то есть".

Примечание. А проценты правильно написаны?

Comment: Здесь главное запятая, а проценты примерные.

Comment: Может быть, 10,1 % , а то  для 101 %   общее количество учащихся будет меньше 1235 человек.

Comment: Ерунда. В современной России бывает и 146%.  А тут все просто. 1235 человек (из них 1223 ученика и 12 учителей) приняли участие в конкурсе лучшей пародии на завуча.